# What does $1/I$ mean?

Tags: electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

Using Ohm's law, I want to get the resistance over voltage.
$$V=RI \implies
V/I = R \implies
1/I = R/V $$
Resistance over voltage gives me the inverse of the current. But what does the inverse of the current mean - what does it describe?

I am struggling and it makes no sense. It would make more sense if I wanted to get the voltage over resistance:
$$V=RI \implies
V/R = I$$
It just gives me the current.

I really can't come up with any suggestions other than it simply describes $1/I$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does $1/v$ mean when $v$ is a velocity? If $v$ is the distance traveled per unit time, then $1/v$ is the time it takes to travel a unit distance. If $I$ is the amount of charge flowing by in a unit time, then $1/I$ is the amount of time it takes for a unit amount of charge to flow by.

---

In terms more specific to the problem at hand, let's make sense of the relation
$$\frac{1}{I} = \frac{R}{V}.$$
The left-hand-side can be interpreted as the amount of time it takes for a unit amount of charge to flow by. This quantity is proportional to $R$ (given a fixed $V$), which makes good sense: a larger resistance means it should take *longer* for charge to flow past. This quantity is also *inversely* proportional to $V$ (given fixed $R$), which also make good sense. An increased potential difference $V$ means that there is a larger force on the particles, and therefore it should take less time for them to move along.